# Search in Page Javascript - One result error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a 'find in page' search box and have found some javascript code that works great. If there is more than one string, pressing enter cycles between the results and then goes back to the beginning. However if there is only one result pressing enter again after the initial search throws up the not found alert. Is there any way of stopping the alert from showing when pressing enter again on single results?

Here is the code:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

I've looked through the code to see if there's anything obvious but I'm new to javascript and can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One approach could be to only allow search if the search term has changed...so you need to store the previous search string and on enter press, validate if the new term is different and only then calling the search function.....

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. would this remove the ability to cycle through multiple results?

Comment: I am not getting it when you say cycle through multiple results..do you mean that you have some kind of lazy loading in place?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better. If I search 'forum' and it's on the page multiple times, pressing enter will jump to the next section of the page that has the word 'forum' and keeps doing this until you get back to the beginning. This isn't something I want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.find` isn't well supported. I'd advise against using it.

That said, your attempt with

```
while(window.find(str, 0, 1)) continue;
```

to "rewind" the search to the beginning won't work when there's only one result because the browser has that result already highlighted - there *is* no result before (or after) the highlighted one.

One solution is to search backwards for something which you know does exist (like the first letter from `document.body.innerHTML` for example) until you reach the beginning instead.

Note that this little hack would still probably fail if you were searching for the only instance of the first word in the document!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now see where the issue is. Is there an alternative to `window.find` that I can use?

Comment: Not if you want to have the features of the browser's `find` functionality. You could of course regex your way through the body's text and wrap matches in spans (maybe with helpful data attributes or styles) you could then manipulate to your heart's content...